# Is it possible to sort a number with alphabet in oracle10g

Tags: oracle10g

I have data like abc1, abc2, abcK. The result after sort should display like abcK, abc1, abc2.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Specify a different collating sequence, either by using `ALTER SESSION` to change the collating sequence for your entire session or by using NLSSORT to change the collating sequence for a single ORDER BY. For example,

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  ORDER BY NLSSORT(YOUR_COLUMN, 'NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN')
```

will order letters before numbers.  [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4867b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **CASE** expression in the **ORDER BY** clause.

For example,

```
order by
  case when translate(column,'x0123456789','x') is null then 2
       else 1
  end, column;
```

The **TRANSLATE** would evaluate the pure strings as **NULL**. Thus, the case would return 2, else for all others, 1. Thus, any string having a number, i.e. **alphanumeric** values would be below the pure **alphabets**.